# How to solve the following polynomial equation?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, determinant

> How to find the eigenvalues of the following $4 \times 4$ matrix?
>
> \begin{pmatrix}
> pq+1&&0&& 0&& -pq\\
> 0&& pq+p&& -(p-1)&& -pq\\
> 0&& -(q-1) && pq+q&& -pq\\
> -(p-1)(q-1) && -(q-1) && -(p-1) && pq\\
> \end{pmatrix}

The characteristic polynomial is
$$\det\begin{pmatrix}
x-(pq+1)&&0&& 0&& pq\\
0&& x-(pq+p)&& (p-1)&& pq\\
0&& (q-1) && x-(pq+q)&& pq\\
(p-1)(q-1) && (q-1) && (p-1) && x-pq\\
\end{pmatrix}$$

But I am unable to understand how to simplify the above determinant and get the roots of the above.

Can someone please help in this?

Comment: @Dietrich Burde has given you the answer. But you can reduce the problem at once (the row sums are all $1$) by changing the basis to $e_1,e_2, e_3, e_1+e_2+e_3+e_4$. Perhaps with a bit of context the other eigenvalues are also clearer?

Comment: @ancientmathematician; I understand that since row sums equal $1$ so $1$ is an eigenvalue of this matrix. But how can I find the other 3 ? Can you kindly explain

Comment: If you use the basis I suggest it reduces to a $3\times 3$ problem,which is "easy" (!). But I am more interested in the context: what problem does this solve?

Comment: @ancientmathematician I’d bet that $p$ and $q$ are probabilities. $1-p$ and $1-q$ turn up repeatedly.

Comment: Yes, @amd , but I'd like to know what the problem is to get a grip on the underlying structure.

Answer (score 1):

The characteristic polynomial is given by
$$
f(t)=t^4 + t^3( - 4pq - p - q - 1) + t^2(5p^2q^2 + 3p^2q + 3pq^2 + 4pq + 2
p + 2q - 1) + t( - 2p^3q^3 - 2p^3q^2 - 2p^2q^3 - 5p^2q^2 - 5p^2q - 5pq^
2 + 2pq - p - q + 1) + 2pq(p^2q^2 + p^2q + pq^2 + p + q - 1).
$$
This can be factored as
$$
f(t)=- (2pq - t)(pq + p + q - t - 1)(pq - t + 1)(t - 1),
$$
so that the roots are obvious.

Comment: The problem is I dont want this type of direct calculation. I want to do a step by step calculation to know how to reduce the above determinant

Comment: You can use the Laplace expansion step by step like [here](https://www.sophia.org/tutorials/4-x-4-determinants--2) for $4\times 4$. If you are only interested in this step by step calculation and not in the result you can take an easier $4\times 4$ example like in the video.